# how to specify the value of our checkbox

Tags: html, angular, checkbox, return-value, angular-ngmodel

I want that when the user checks on checkbox, the value be "l.code" instead of a Boolean value

Here's my code

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Critères : </label>&nbsp;
    <div class="checkbox-inline" *ngFor="let l of lesCriteres; let i= index">
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" [value]="l.code" [(ngModel)]="actif.lesCriteresActifs[i].critere.code">{{l.code}}
      </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

But it does not work ! when I check, it gives me "true" instead of "l.code". Thanks !

Comment: Why are you using a checkbox for this? Checkboxes are suppose to be for boolean values.

Comment: because I want to give the user the ability to choose one or more options. With the radio buttons, he can only choose one option

Comment: Did you try `value="l.code"` instead of `[value]="l.code"`?

Comment: yeah and there are no changes

Comment: @PowerGirl https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9qkk8l try this code

Comment: @PowerGirl I will post it as answer..please accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like below :

HTML:

```
<div *ngFor="let data of emails">
    <input type="checkbox" [value]="data.email" (change)="onChange(data.email, $event.target.checked)"> {{data.email}}<br>
</div>
```

ts:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder, FormArray, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  name = 'Angular 6';
emailFormArray = [];
  emails = [{ email: "email1" }, { email: "email2" }, { email: "email3" }, { email: 'email4' }]
  myForm: FormGroup;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.myForm = this.fb.group({
      useremail: this.fb.array([])
    });
  }

  onChange(email: string, isChecked: boolean) {
    if (isChecked) {
      this.emailFormArray.push(email);
    } else {
      let index = this.emailFormArray.findIndex(x =>{ 
        console.log(x);
        return x == email
        });
      console.log(index)
      this.emailFormArray.splice(index,1);
    }
    console.log(this.emailFormArray)
  }

}
```

[STACKBLITZ](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9qkk8l?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Answer (score 2):

You can use "change" event handler with event binding on checkbox.

### In html

```
<form>
    <div *ngFor="let l of lesCriteres">
        <input type="checkbox" value="l.code" (change)="onChangeEvent($event, l.code)"> {{l.code}}<br>
    </div>
</form>
```

### In ts

```
onChangeEvent(eventValue, valueOfCheckbox){
  alert(valueOfCheckbox);
}
```